# Passing view-controller into another view-controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

i have 10 uiviewcontrollers each creating a type of question to the user.
Each has several layers, uilabels and data.
All 10 should call the '***disp_correct_anim***' viewcontroller when the user's answer is correct and the '***disp_fail_anim***' when the answer is wrong.
These two new controllers need to have all the subviews and data of the main viewcontroller.
They then create a few more layers and then a animation will start.
My problem is that i don't know how to pass the entire viewcontroller to the '***disp_fail_anim***' lets say

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Calling the NSobject to create the data of the app
// ================================================================================
circleModel = [[Circles_3 alloc] init];



// Draw a shape
// ================================================================================
UIColor * colr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.55 green:0.55 blue:0.55 alpha:1.0];
CAShapeLayer * down_rect = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGRect low_rect= [[circleModel.Architectural_rectangles objectForKey:@"Control_rect"]  CGRectValue];
down_rect.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:low_rect].CGPath;
down_rect.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
down_rect.strokeColor = colr.CGColor;
down_rect.lineWidth = 1.5;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:down_rect];

// Display some text
// ================================================================================
NSAttributedString * Que_Text=circleModel.Question_string;
CGRect recty= [[circleModel.Architectural_rectangles objectForKey:@"Question_rect"]  CGRectValue];
UILabel *Question_text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:recty];
Question_text.AttributedText = Que_Text;
Question_text.numberOfLines = 0;
Question_text.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
Question_text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:Question_text];


  }






// Then i have some touch methods and when the touch is over

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if (circleModel.Correct_answer==button)
    disp_correct_anim * correct_anim = [[disp_correct_anim alloc] init];

else
    disp_fail_anim * fail_anim = [[disp_fail_anim alloc] init];
}


// The 'disp_fail_anim' and 'disp_correct_anim' are 2 animations each being a viewcontroller.
```

Answer (score 1):

You sound confused. Animations are not view controllers. View controllers don't share views with other view controllers.

It sounds to me like you need to create a parent class for all your view controllers that implements a couple of common animation methods, one for a correct answer, and one for a wrong answer. All 10 of your view controllers would be subclasses of this base class and therefore have the method built into them.